# jQuery Datatable sort by column header

Tags: jquery, datatables

Basically, jQuery Datatable allow us to sort data by column index.

```
"order": [1, 'desc']
```

I wonder if we can sort by column header name? For example:

```
"order": ['my_column_name', 'desc']
```

Thankyou
Alex

Comment: [**No**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order). First hit in google... And what is the "header name"? Is it the `text()` content, is it a `name="name"` attribute or something else...? You could simply map your header names into integer constants, and use those constants instead of indexes.  But what should be the benefit of doing that? A column index is basically just another name for the column anyway. `1` is the unique name for the second column...

Comment: There is always a tweak, like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/257jmovv/** but still cannot see the purpose, and it would only work more or less hardcoded on DOM tables anyway.

Answer (score 5):

> [Is there a way to use the name, data or class of the column in order to set the default column sort?](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/28423/sorting-ordering-columns-using-column-name-data-class)
>   No - not at this time.

Although this thread is posted in June-2015 but still I couldn't find such functionality in latest version of DataTable.

*As a side note!*  You have to provide `column index` while ordering data of DataTable but you can get `Column Name` on which ordering is applied.

```
var order = table.order();
var columnIndex = order[0][0]; //column index
var orderDirection =order[0][1]; // asc or desc

//Get column header text;
var title = table.column(order[0][0]).header();
var columnName = $(title).html(); //Column Name
```

<kbd>**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/rsnpf7cj/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

First find the column index by jquery,

Then insert the column index in datatable function.

```
var sort_col = $('#table').find("th:contains('your column name')")[0].cellIndex;

$('#table').dataTable({             
    order: [[ sort_col, 'desc' ]]                
  });
```

This worked for me. Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: This works for me. an absolute solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to fix this problem

```
var column1 = table.parents('table').find("th:contains('Your th text')")[0].cellIndex; 
var column2 = table.parents('table').find("th:contains('Your th text')")[0].cellIndex;
table.parents('table').dataTable({
  order: [[column1, 'asc'], [column2, 'asc']]
});
```